# Representing and editing numerical tables in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabular

I need a class in .Net 4.0 which is suitable for displaying and editing numerical tables. Rows and  columns headers should be supported. What are possible candidates for this task? What I don't want to is writing a lot of plumbing code concerning updating or saving changes.

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.Controls.GridView